# Replacing and Inserting data to users

Tags: php, database

How do you add new data of **a particular** student in a database
eg. Existing Data

Student Name : abc
Jobscope1 : HR

what I want the database to show

Student Name : abc
Jobscope1 : IT

Is this the correct query?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO student_details.".
   "(jobscope1)".
   "VALUES('$jobscope1')";
```

Nothing is being shown or replaced in my database for the particular abc student.
Instead a new row is created with null fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update a row in your database you must use the UPDATE statement

```
UPDATE student_details SET jobscope1 = 'new value' WHERE student_id = {id};
```

otherwise as Sharikov Vladislav mentioned use the INSERT statement which creates a new row of a new student.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean adding data connected with existing student? You should use this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO student_details (jobscope1, student_id) VALUES ('$jobscope1', '$student_id')";
```